# Rxjs: Poll data until predicate is met

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

```
import {Observable} from '@reactivex/rxjs'

// This is a fake API polling, this data is in reality coming from
// the server
const fakePoll$ = Observable.from([
  {
    status: 'initialized',
    data: {...},
  },
  {
    status: 'progress',
    data: {...},
  },
  {
    status: 'progress',
    data: {...},
  },
  {
    status: 'progress',
    data: {...},
  },
  {
    status: 'completed',
    data: {...},
  },
  ...
  {
    status: 'completed',
    data: {...},
  },
])

fakePoll$
  .takeWhile(x => x.status != 'completed')
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

This snippet returns all the progress and initialized statuses:

```
initialized
progress
progress
progress
```

But I need to get the first completed also like a takeWhile but inclusive.

Comment: I believe you have to use repeat when using an api assuming it is a promise returning call. I did this as in plnkr.co/edit/6fBPFCus3HhZmCFBXFKq. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also please refer to my question where i tried this in 3 different ways. Please feel free to comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248530/server-polling-using-rxjs-till-condition-is-met

Answer (score 1):

You could consider adding it back like here, if that is all you need :

```
Rx.Observable.concat(fakePoll$
  .takeWhile(x => x != 'completed'), Rx.Observable.from('completed'))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: The snippet I wrote is obviously a dummy example to show my problem. In my real application I fakePoll its a polling to an API.

Comment: Alright, but it does not change the fact that if you know what is the terminal value you can reinsert it. Or in your use case you do not know what is the value which ended the polling?

Comment: Yes, the fake poll is in reality a fake polling to an api full of other values that I cant know. Maybe I have to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use repeat when using an api assuming it is a promise returning call. I did this as in
 [Server Polling](http://plnkr.co/edit/6fBPFCus3HhZmCFBXFKq)
   // Code goes here

```
angular.module('rxApp', ['rx'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http, rx) {
    function getRandom(){
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1)) + 1;
    }

    function getResults(){
       console.log("returning promise");
       return $http({
          url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&callback=JSON_CALLBACK",
          method: "jsonp",
          params: {
            action: "opensearch",
            search: 'eclipse',
            format: "json"
          }
        });
    }
    var toBeRepeated =  rx.Observable
    .fromPromise(getResults).repeat()
    .map(response => { console.log(response); return response.data[1]; })
    .map(results => {
        var rs = results[getRandom()];
        console.log(rs);
        return rs;
    });             

    var source = toBeRepeated.takeWhile(rs => rs.indexOf('play') === -1);
        source.subscribe(function(item){
        console.log("item:"+ item);
    },err => { console.log(err); },completed => {console.log("completed :" + completed);} );
});
```

Hope this helps.